# PHP SQL Search Page returns an error

Tags: php, html, sql

Okay guys, maybe I can get some definitive answers for this newest issue. This PHP section doesn't return any responses, however, I know the data is there. Does anyone know why this returns the text "Error"?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Search</title>
<style type="text/css">
    table {
        background-color: #FCF;
    }

    th {
        width: 150px;
        text-align: left;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Search</h1>


<form method="post" action="search.php">
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true"/>

<label> Search | Category:
    <select name="category">
        <option value="fname">FName</option>
        <option value="lname">LName</option>
    </select>
</label>

<label>Search Criteria: <input type="text" name="criteria"/></label>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

// connect to DB
include('connect.php');

$category = $_POST['category'];
$criteria = $_POST['criteria'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE category = '$category'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query) or die ('Error');


echo "<table>";
    echo "<thead>";
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>First Name</th>";
            echo "<th>Last Name</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
    echo "</thead>";
    echo "<tbody>";
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<th>" . $row['fname'] . "</th>";
                    echo "<th>" . $row['lname'] . "</th>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
    echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
}  
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you specify what the error is?

Comment: You need to add some error handling to your database calls: `or die ('Error')`

Answer (score 5):

Probably because of this line: `$result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query) or die ('Error');`
If the query fails, the script will stop and print "Error".
You might want to put something like `mysqli_error($dbcon)` instead of `'Error'` and in this specific case, I would recommend echoing out the query to see how it looks.

And please, either escape the POST data before using it in a database query, or rather use prepared statements!